# spring mvc model error mapping

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on spring mvc and creating a one to many relationship between 2 tables. I have 2 models:

1. ContractHeader 1:many
2. ContractEntitlement many:1

ContractHeader.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT_HEADER")
public class ContractHeader {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contractHeader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ContractEntitlement> contractEntitlements;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public List<ContractEntitlement> getContractEntitlements() {
        return contractEntitlements;
    }

    public void setContractEntitlements(List<ContractEntitlement> contractEntitlements) {
        this.contractEntitlements = contractEntitlements;
    }

}
```

ContractEntitlement.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT_ENTITLEMENT")
public class ContractEntitlement {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private ContractHeader contractHeader; 

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ContractHeader getContractHeader() {
        return contractHeader;
    }

    public void setContractHeader(ContractHeader contractHeader) {
        this.contractHeader = contractHeader;
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error when publishing in eclipse sts:

```
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.at.ccts.model.ContractEntitlement column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"). Please see server.log for more details.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See `server.log` for more details?

Answer (score 1):

In your entity **ContractHeader** your mapping will give a table with two columns with name **id** ,change the name attribute in the @JoinColumn

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idContractHeader")
private ContractHeader contractHeader;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use as link this:-

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ContractHeader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ContractEntitlement> contractEntitlements;
```